# Objective-C Mac OSX app - getting variable from another delegate?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

EchoAppDelegate.h

```
NSString *theString;
```

EchoAppDelegate.m

```
/////being declared somewhere here//////
theString = [lastUserInputJabber stringValue];
```

ChatController.m

```
//Get theString variable from echoappdelegate
NSString *theStringDiff = theString;
```

How would I do this?

Comment: You wouldn't, that would break encapsulation. Make an API to expose things. That said, your app delegate is the wrong place for this type of information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EchoAppDelegate` must provide a method that returns that string, or make that string a public ivar. For instance, you could implement a getter method like:

```
// EchoAppDelegate.h
@interface EchoAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSString *theString;
}
- (NSString *)theString;
@end
```

and

```
// EchoAppDelegate.m
@implementation EchoAppDelegate
- (NSString *)theString { return theString; }
@end
```

or make it a declared property and have Objective-C automatically provide a getter method:

```
// EchoAppDelegate.h
@interface EchoAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSString *theString;
}
@property (readonly) NSString *theString;
@end
```

and

```
// EchoAppDelegate.m
@implementation EchoAppDelegate
@synthesize theString;
@end
```

(Depending on your target/compiler, you may not need to declare the ivar — the modern runtime and recent enough compilers can automatically create backing ivars for declared properties. Also, depending on your design, you might want to make `theString` a `readwrite copy` property, in which case you’ll also get a setter method that copies an arbitrary string onto `theString`.)

Having done that, your application delegate now exposes a method that returns that string. When you need to access it in an implementation file other than the application delegate one, use `-[NSApplication delegate]` to obtain the delegate, and then use the getter method to obtain the string:

```
// ChatController.m
#import "EchoAppDelegate.h"

- (void)someMethod {
    // Get a reference to the application delegate instance
    EchoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (EchoAppDelegate *)[NSApp delegate];

    // Use the application delegate instance to get theString
    NSString *theStringDiff = [appDelegate theString];
}
```

As jer pointed out, you should ponder whether the application delegate is the right place to keep that string. The application delegate should be concerned with information and behaviour that applies to the entire application.

Comment: @Josh Heh, you’ll reach that in no time. :)

Comment: Awesome, how about with voids? Like if I wanted to run, sendText from another delegate?

Comment: I'm still a little confused about how that works. Thank you again, you explained it very clearly.

Comment: How would I both implement it in the .h and then reach it from the separate .m file.

Comment: @Elijah You need to declare the behaviour you want in EchoAppDelegate.h and implement it in EchoAppDelegate.m. Having done that, you need to import EchoAppDelegate.h in other .m files, use `[NSApp delegate]` to get a reference to the delegate, and then call the method you want.

Comment: @Elijah The same applies to any communication between objects of different classes. In one class, declare and implement a method. In another class, import the header file of the first class, obtain a reference to an instance of the first class, and then call the method.

Comment: Hmm...odd. I did this, and it's not running it.

Comment: @Elijah It’s not `ChatController`. The application delegate class is `EchoAppDelegate`.